# Can't install java 8 on linux mint

Tags: java, linux-mint

Linux Mint 19.3

I need to install jdk 8.

I try this:

```
sudo apt update
```

result:

```
Ign:1 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages tricia InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages tricia Release
Get:3 http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync InRelease [4,516 B]
Hit:4 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu tricia InRelease
Hit:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:18 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu tricia Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.239.195.37 443]
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:3 http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BE66CC4C3F171DE2
Hit:20 https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu tricia Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BE66CC4C3F171DE2
E: The repository 'http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

then

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-8-jdk is already the newest version (8u252-b09-1~18.04).
openjdk-8-jre is already the newest version (8u252-b09-1~18.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fluid-soundfont-gs gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 icoutils libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3:i386 libcapi20-3 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcups2:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libexif12:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgd3:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu60:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libnettle6:i386
  libnvidia-common-435 libodbc1:i386 libodbc1 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio6.1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386
  libtiff5:i386 libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine-development libwrap0:i386
  libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386
  libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 linux-headers-5.3.0-40 linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic
  linux-modules-5.3.0-40-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-40-generic ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion python3-evdev vulkan-utils wine-stable
  wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386 wine64-development winehq-stable xaw3dg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

but when I try

```
java -version
```

I get error:

java -version

Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Comment: I would suggest opening another terminal and check again with the same command java --version.

Comment: @executable Not help. Same error

Comment: Check if you have a .jdks in your home directory

Comment: @executable In my home directory has no .jdks

Comment: Find where he binary "java" exists, then check if it is on your path.

Comment: find / -name java

Comment: env | grep PATH

Answer (score 0):

I try this but it also not help:

1. Download jdk 8 from https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml
2. Unzip archive to local folder `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_251/`
3. Create file `/home/alexei/.bash_profile` with the next content:

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_251/
4. Restart computer.
5. Open terminal and run `java -version` but I get error:

   Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

   sudo apt install default-jre
   sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
   sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless